# from requests import Session as OriginalSession ImportError: cannot import name 'Session'

Tags: python, session, bitcoin, coinbase-api

I don't understand the error I get and searching online was not helpful.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/<path>/file.py", line 1, in <module>
    from coinmarketcap import Market
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/coinmarketcap/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .core import Market
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/coinmarketcap/core.py", line 8, in <module>
    import requests_cache
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests_cache/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from .core import(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests_cache/core.py", line 14, in <module>
    from requests import Session as OriginalSession
ImportError: cannot import name 'Session'
```

It seems to be generated from the very first line where the import and code is the following:

```
from coinmarketcap import Market


cmc = Market()
coins = cmc.ticker(limit=15)  # assumes Dash in top 15.
print(coins)
```

Comment: What version of the `requests` module do you have installed? If requests is pretty outdated this may be the cause. Maybe try `pip install -U requests` then?

Comment: I am using PyCharm therefore I believe the latest version is downloaded

Comment: Can you please confirm?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps but I had similar issue with import - turned out I have created requests.py file and imported stuff from there. It caused namespace clash as other libraries I used in the project were dependent on built-in requests module.